# Angular: How can the Router be injected in a component when it hasn't been declared in any provider?

Tags: angular, angular-routing

Suppose we have the following component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private router: Router) { }
}
```

In order for something to be injected in a component, we have to either declare it in the providers array of the component/super-component, or in the module. Since `Router` has not been declared by either ways, how can it be available in the constructor?

Is it because its provided by default in Angular?

Answer (score 1):

The `Router` is provided by the `RouterModule`, [github repo](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/ede65dbede75b89ef759df780fadb6c2769d1133/packages/router/src/router_module.ts#L57) :

```
export const ROUTER_PROVIDERS: Provider[] = [
  Location,
  {provide: UrlSerializer, useClass: DefaultUrlSerializer},
  {
    provide: Router,
    useFactory: setupRouter,
...

static forRoot(routes: Routes, config?: ExtraOptions): ModuleWithProviders<RouterModule> {
    return {
      ngModule: RouterModule,
      providers: [
        ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
...
```